# How do I translate this sentence into propositional logic notation?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If one were to translate a sentence in the form of "p, but q" into propositional logic notation, would they write "p -> q", or "p v q"?

Comment: What does "p but q" mean?

Comment: I share the confusion of @manlet_hunter.  One possible interpretation is that $~p~$ must be true, whenever it is not the case that $~q~$ is true.  **If** this is the intended interpretation, then the translation would be $~(\neg q) \implies p.$